# jQuery validate remote not submiting form after validate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a form that I am validating with jQuery validate.

It works fine but I can't get the form submitted after the remote validation returns from the server.

The php script that validates in the server is returning "true" (without quotes).

This is the code for my form validation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.datePicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy',
                        autoSize: true 
            });

            // validate 
            jQuery('#ivru-report-form').validate({
                rules: {
                    date: {
                        required: true,
                        remote: {
                            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
                            type: "post",
                            data: {
                                action:'ivru_add_item_validate_date',
                                page: function() {
                                    return jQuery( "#ivru-hidden-page" ).val();
                                },
                                date: function() {
                                    return jQuery( "#ivru-txt-date" ).val();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    userfile: {
                        required: true,
                        extension: "doc,docx,xls,xlsx,pdf"
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    userfile: {
                        extension: "Allowed extension types are: doc, docx, xls, xlsx, pdf."
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

*It works fine but I can't get the form submitted after the remote validation returns from the server.*
If it works fine then it is not jQuery fault but PHP action in your form.

And it shouldn't be like this:

```
url: "admin-ajax.php"
```

on place of

> `url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>'`

http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method

Comment: That url is ok, because I am getting the response from the server.